# Interlacing two binary numbers together in Arduino C

Tags: c#, arduino, binary, arduino-uno, binary-data

So I've come across a strange need to 'merge' two numbers:

```
byte one;
byte two;
```

into an `int three;` with the first bit being the first bit of `one`, the second bit being the first bit of `two`, the third being the second bit of `one` and so on.

So with these two numbers:

```
01001000
00010001
```

would result in

`0001001001000010`

---

A more didatic illustration of the interlacing operation:

```
byte one = 0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0
byte two = 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1
result   = 00 01 00 10 01 00 00 10
```

Comment: *into an int three; with the first bit being the first bit of one, the second bit being the first bit of two, the third being the second bit of one and so on* and for `01001000 00010001` it should be according to your explanation this `0010000110000001` but **NOT** this `0001001001000010`! Am I wrong?

Comment: Hi @Yahya, yes, was my first perception, and make more sense as "standard interlacing"... Check illustration, I edited. As implementarion, no problem, is only a case to swap, using  `f(b,a)` instead `f(a,b)` in the presented solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Sorry misread your question completely.

The following code should do:

```
public static int InterlacedMerge(byte low, byte high)
{
    var result = 0;

    for (var offset = 0; offset < 8; offset++)
    {
        var mask = 1 << offset;
        result |= ((low & mask) | ((high & mask)) << 1) << offset;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I am not, by any means, very smart when it comes to bit twiddling so there probably is a  more efficient way to do this. That said, I think this will do the job but I haven't tested it, so make sure you do.

P.D: There are some unnecessary parenthesis in the code but I'm never sure about bitwise operators precedence so I find it easier to read the way its written.

UPDATE2: Here is the same code a little more verbose to make it easier to follow:

```
public static int InterlacedMerge(byte low, byte high)
{
    var result = 0;

    for (var offset = 0; offset < 8; offset++)
    {
        //Creates a mask with the current bit set to one: 00000001,
        //00000010, 00000100, and so on...
        var mask = 1 << offset; 

        //Creates a number with the current bit set to low's bit value.
        //All other bits are 0
        var lowAndMask = low & mask; 

        //Creates a number with the current bit set to high's bit value.
        //All other bits are 0
        var highAndMask = high & mask; 

        //Create a merged pair where the lowest bit is the low 's bit value
        //and the highest bit is high's bit value.
        var mergedPair = lowAndMask | (highAndMask << 1);

        //Ors the mergedPair into the result shifted left offset times
        //Because we are merging two bits at a time, we need to
        //shift 1 additional time for each preceding bit.                              
        result |= mergedPair << offset;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: @Yahya Its standard bit twiddling. I'll make the code more verbose a little to make it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

@inbetween answered while I was writing this; similar solution, different phrasing.

You'll have to write a loop. You'll test one bit in each of the two inputs. You'll set a bit in an output for each input. You'll shift all three values one place. Maybe something like this (untested):

```
#define TOPBIT 32768

for /* 16 times */
    if ( value1 & 1 )  out |= TOPBIT;
    out >>= 1;

    if ( value2 & 1 )  out |= TOPBIT;
    out >>= 1;

    b1 >>= 1;
    b2 >>= 1;
```